# Can not handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (java.util.List) not compatible with managed type (ForumAnswerReplay)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Forum Answer saving time facing issue.before i saved successfully using @JsonIgnore but now i removed @JsonIgnore annonation.and added  @JsonBackReference and  @JsonManagedReference.

**Stack Trace**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (java.util.List) not compatible with managed type (com.tta.abcd.model.ForumAnswerReplay)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase._resolveManagedReferenceProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:790)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:516)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:296)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:443)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.createContextual(CollectionDeserializer.java:196)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.createContextual(CollectionDeserializer.java:26)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleSecondaryContextualization(DeserializationContext.java:681)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:445)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.findDeserializer(StdDeserializer.java:967)
```

**Forum.java**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="Forum")
    public class Forum {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="forumId")
    private Long forumId;

    @Column(name="question")
    private String question;

    @Column(columnDefinition="varchar(1000)",name="discription")
    private String discription;

    @Column(name="postedDate")
    private Date postedDate;

    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "forumId")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<ForumAnswer> forumList;
    }
```

**ForumAnswer.java**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="ForumAnswer")
    public class ForumAnswer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="forumAnswerId")
    private Long forumAnswerId;

    @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "forumId",insertable=true, updatable=true,nullable=true)
    private Forum forum;

    @Column(name="answer")
    private String answer;

    @Column(name="answerDate")
    private Date answerDate;

    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "forumAnswerId")
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<ForumAnswerReplay> forumAnswerReplayList;

    @Transient
    private List<ForumAnswerReplay> faqReplayList;
}
```

**ForumAnswerReplay.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ForumAnswerReplay")
public class ForumAnswerReplay {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="replayId")
    private Long replayId;

    @Column(name="replayToAnswer")
    private String replayToAnswer;

    @Column(name="replayToAnswerDate")
    private Date replayToAnswerDate;


    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="forumAnswerId",insertable=true,updatable=true,nullable=true)
        @JsonManagedReference
    private ForumAnswer forumAnswer;

    @Transient
    private String message;
}
```

**Controller Code:**

```
public ForumAnswer saveForumAns(@RequestBody ForumAnswer forumAns, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpSession session,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    ForumAnswer forumDetails = forumService.saveForumAns(forumAns, bindingResult, session);
    if (forumDetails != null) {
        forumDetails.setMessage("success");
    }
    else {
        forumDetails.setMessage("failed");
    }
    return forumDetails;
}
```

**DAO:**

```
public ForumAnswer saveForumAns(ForumAnswer forumAns, BindingResult bindingResult) {

    final Session session = getSession();
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createQuery("UPDATE ForumAnswer set answer =:answer,"
                + "forumAnswerId =:forumAnswerId,farmerUuid =:farmerUuid, answerDate =:answerDate");
        query.setParameter("answer", forumAns.getAnswer());
        query.setParameter("forumAnswerId", forumAns.getForumAnswerId());
        query.setParameter("farmerUuid", forumAns.getFarmer());
        query.setParameter("answerDate", forumAns.getAnswerDate());
        session.merge(forumAns);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("error while saving forum details" + e);
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }

    return forumAns;
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think you have misplaced @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference.

@JsonManagedReference : its forward part of reference so it will apply on collection type.

@JsonBackReference: its back part of reference.

so your code must be like

```
  @JsonManagedReference 
     private List<ForumAnswerReplay> forumAnswerReplayList;

 @JsonBackReference
    private ForumAnswer forumAnswer;
```

you can also use `@JsonIdentityInfo` you have to apply

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
                  property  = "forumAnswerId", 
                  scope     = Long.class)
public class ForumAnswer {
}

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
                  property  = "replyId", 
                  scope     = Long.class)
public class ForumAnswerReplay {
}
```

Comment: thank you for your replay. in properties level instead of  @JsonManagedReference  i'm using @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
                  property  = "forumAnswerId") but not working.same issue i'm facing.

Comment: @umapati: you have to remove `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` and add `@JsonIdentityInfo` on both class.

Comment: i removed both annotations and i added  @JsonIdentityInfo class level. now data is saving successfully but retrieving time data not reaching to ui.

Comment: you have only posted code for save. update your question and write code you tried for retrieval.

Comment: So ```@JsonBackReference``` goes only with ```@ManyToOne``` and ```@JsonManagedReference``` goes only with ```@OneToMany``` ?

Answer (score 6):

Remove  @JsonManagedReference in ForumAnswer class.

ForumAnswer class:

```
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "forumAnswerId")
    private List<ForumAnswerReplay> forumAnswerReplayList;
```

In **ForumAnswerReplay:**

```
@JsonBackReference
public ForumAnswer getForumAnswer() {
    return forumAnswer;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use @JsonBackReference for @OneToMany and @JsonManagedReference for @ManyToOne relation to allow Jackson to better handle the relation.

Comment: What about @ManyToMany?

Comment: If you only want to avoid recursion, you can use @JsonIdentityInfo for Parent class. You can see https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion for further clarification.
Thank you!

Comment: Everyone links to that one "tutorial" at 'baeldung', but it doesn't really explain anything.

Comment: \@JsonBackReference goes on the child, the non-collection \@ManyToOne.
https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonBackReference.html
\@JsonManagedReference goes on the parent, the\@OneToMany collection

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue recently, I tried to debug the code, I searched all around the internet and what helped finally was this:

Make sure you set your ***@JsonBackReference*** and ***@JsonManagedReference*** to have a unique ***value***, for instance in my **Department class** I have:

```
    @JsonManagedReference(value = "faculty-department")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
    private List<Faculty> faculties;
```

and in my **Faculty class**, I have:

```
    @JsonBackReference(value = "faculty-department")
    @ManyToOne
    private Department department;
```

When working on a project with just two entities, I noticed that the code was OK, but when the code base grew to more than 5 entities. This error tends to occur if you have multiple relationships with more than one ***@JsonBackReference*** in the same entity/class.

If the code builds successfully you may still get a 415 media unsupported error even if you select application/json as your content type while posting, so you will have to set the value as a unique key shared across related entities.

Using SpringBoot 3.1.1 at the time of this answer.